# SVG not showing properly in tinymce because for foreignObject tags

Tags: angular, svg, tinymce

I am using tinymce v6 with an Angular application (v16).
We would like to add SVG figures, generated by mermaidjs, to the documents written using tinymce.

The SVG generation using mermaidjs is working perfectly. The figure is shown correctly in the Angular app.
However, when we try to inject the SVG in tinymce, the text is not shown.

We tried to add the different tags of the SVG to `extended_valid_elements`. However, the tag `foreignObject` is removed once added to tinymce.

We also tried allowing all tags using the `valid_elements` attribute but it does nothing. The tag `foreignObject` keeps being removed.

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thank you,